# ViewPagerAdapter issue

Tags: android

So I got the "SlidingTabLayout" code from this [github repository](https://github.com/hiteshbpatel/Android_Blog_Projects/tree/master/AndroidSlidingTabLayoutExample/app/src), it has no errors but each time I try to run it / debug it, it just bombs out.

As far as I can tell the code that is making it bomb out is these lines :

```
view_pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
view_pager.setAdapter(adapter); -- Specifically this line.
```

[image]

I don't know if this could be contributing to the problem I'm having.

Also I read something that says

> "You should use a more specific implementation of this(ViewPager) either  FragmentPagerAdapter or FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

The problem is in the ActivityMain.

Comment: add the log so we can know the issue, the adapter should be null at that point because it's not initialised before if you add on brake point after you will see that it's not null

Comment: I was right in saying the setAdapter being null was the problem or could be the problem                                                                                                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter)' on a null object reference

Comment: the `view_pager` is null not the adapter

Comment: Found a solution, thanks.

Comment: share the solution so any body fix it

Comment: Man, I can't remember what I did, but I'll go through the code and will share as soon as I find out what change fixed it.

Comment: Oussema Arouna, I'm not exactly sure what I added but I think after having added this line to the content_main.xml everything got fixed.                                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"